# retrieve members of a nested distribution group in outlook using c#

Tags: outlook, add-in

I am developing an Outlook 2013 add-in in which I have to expand the distribution groups(which may or may not be nested) into its constituent member's names as soon as the group is selected from the Outlook Address Book.How can this be achieved?
I am totally novice at it,henceforth no source code has been mentioned.Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest starting from the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx) article in MSDN.

```
private void GetDistributionListMembers()
{
    Outlook.SelectNamesDialog snd =
      Application.Session.GetSelectNamesDialog();
    Outlook.AddressLists addrLists =
      Application.Session.AddressLists;
    foreach (Outlook.AddressList addrList in addrLists)
    {
       if (addrList.Name == "All Groups")
       {
          snd.InitialAddressList = addrList;
          break;
       }
    }
    snd.NumberOfRecipientSelectors =
      Outlook.OlRecipientSelectors.olShowTo;
    snd.ToLabel = "D/L";
    snd.ShowOnlyInitialAddressList = true;
    snd.AllowMultipleSelection = false;
    snd.Display();
    if (snd.Recipients.Count > 0)
    {
       Outlook.AddressEntry addrEntry =
         snd.Recipients[1].AddressEntry;
       if (addrEntry.AddressEntryUserType ==
         Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.
           olExchangeDistributionListAddressEntry)
       {
           Outlook.ExchangeDistributionList exchDL =
             addrEntry.GetExchangeDistributionList();
           Outlook.AddressEntries addrEntries =
             exchDL.GetExchangeDistributionListMembers();
           if (addrEntries != null)
               foreach (Outlook.AddressEntry exchDLMember in addrEntries)
           {
               Debug.WriteLine(exchDLMember.Name);
           }
       }
   }
}
```

See [How to: Get Members of an Exchange Distribution List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb645998.aspx) for more information.

You may find the [How Do I... (Outlook 2013 PIA Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb612741.aspx) section in MSDN helpful.